# Populating jTable from different class

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have two classes, the first is the GUI which has jTable, and the other one for querying database. 
Adding rows to the table within the same class works fine. I used this way:

```
((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).addRow(values);
```

While `values` is a Object[] holding the row content.
This is working fine. But populating has to be done from another class. So I have in the query class:

```
((DefaultTableModel) rg.table.getModel()).addRow(values);
```

While `rg` is an object of the GUI class. And `table` is **public**.

This doesn't do anything not even throwing an exception.

What should I change in my query class? Here's my method in the query class:

```
public void selectPassengers(int rows) {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM brs.passenger";
        try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            Object[] attributes = new Object[9];

            Register rg = new Register();


            while (rs.next()) {
                attributes[0] = String.valueOf(rs.getString(1));
                attributes[1] = rs.getString(2);
                attributes[2] = rs.getString(3);
                attributes[3] = rs.getString(4);
                attributes[4] = rs.getString(5);
                attributes[5] = rs.getString(6);
                attributes[6] = rs.getString(7);
                attributes[7] = rs.getString(8);
                attributes[8] = rs.getString(9);
                ((DefaultTableModel) rg.table.getModel()).addRow(attributes);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

- Fetching data from the DB is fine. I could print them to the console.
- jTable is *I assume* is built correctly. I can tell this because I
  can insert rows correctly but only within the GUI class itself (the
  class where jTable is there).
- Moving the inserting logic to a different class (querying class) is
  where I am stuck.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you are asking us about a bug without showing us code.  Without concrete code, we can only guess what the problem might be, which is not useful to you or future readers.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: Thanks. Edited, I hope it's useful enough now.

Comment: Generate a new `TableModel` from your "population" class which your GUI class can consume

Comment: Could you please explain more? I have tried:
nmodel = new DefaultTableModel();
nmodel.addRow(attributes);
In my populating class.
And then 
table.setModel(db.nmodel);
in my GUI class.
The table clears (gets empty) when I tried this.

Comment: Please create the code which we also can run and debug. In this case we probably can understand, where is your problem. Your current code give us no hint about it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by calling the `frame` object before the `model` object.
So instead of `rg.model.addRow();`, I used `rg.frame.model.addRow();`, after making `frame` public in the GUI class.

Comment: You were told the whole structure of your code was wrong in your last question. Why do you ask a question if you don't listen to the advice. I gave you the simple logic for a better design of your class. Using public variables like this is not a proper design. If you design the class properly you don't have a problem. It was suggested you first get the structure of your code correct and forget about the database. Why did you not post a proper [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks again for the advice. It's appreciated. However, a) I already completed > 80% of the project that had almost 2k lines of code. b) The app will be run only ONCE. That's why I looked for shortcuts. Thanks again for your time :)